# Динамическая перезагрузка с помощью JQuery полученной ссылкой с сервера Java

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlet, jstl

При нажатии на ссылку, я вызываю метод jquery, который отправляет ссылку с параметрами на сервер, от сервера я получаю ссылку с параметрами, которая возвращается в jquery и динамически должна перезагрузить страницу с параметрами, которые будут отображать определённый контекст в index.jsp с помощью jstl.

Ни как не получается открыть ссылку с параметрами которая приходит с сервера в jQuery...

```
    <a onclick="change('/ShowServlet?action=reviews')" title="Отзывы">Отзывы</a>
    <a onclick="change('/ShowServlet?action=contacts')" title="Контакты">Контакты</a>

<core:when test="${param.get('action') == 'reviews'}">
<core:when test="${param.get('action') == 'contacts'}">


function change(href) {
$.get(href, function(html){
    $(document).html(html);)}}


@RequestMapping(value = "/ShowServlet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView service(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("/index");
    return modelAndView;}
```

Comment: вам самим не кажется что в описанной ситуации jquery является лишним звеном?

Comment: "Ни как не получается" - это что значит? Что конкретно происходит?

Comment: вы отправляете на сервер запрос, сервер генерирует ссылку и отдает ее вам. вы переходите по ней. Зачем это все надо? кликайте в обычную ссылку, на сервер уйдет запрос. сервер сгенерит новую ссылку и вернет 302 редирект на нее. все.

Comment: открывается та ссылка на которой я и был, т.е. ссылка без параметров...
Серверная часть не меняется там всё нормально потому как в Ajax всё работает, хочу сделать тоже самое в jquery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл я несколько решений:

- Методы document.open/write/close:

  `function change(href) {
      $.get(href, function(response){
         document.open("text/html", "replace");
         document.write(response);
         document.close();
      )}
   }`

Если не передать параметр `replace`, вызов `document.open` добавляет историю страниц. Таким образом, пользователям придется дважды щелкнуть дважды, чтобы перейти на предыдущую страницу.

- Можно просто вырезать HTML-теги, а затем положить все внутри HTML-элемент:`$('html').html(response.replace(/<html>(.*)<\/html>/, "$1"));`
- Хотя в этом и нет необходимости, для зачистки `$('html').html(response);` делает это всё автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Для перезагрузки из js выполните: window.location = "url" ;